# Maven update with new file with the same version

Tags: file, maven, jar

I am using Maven and have a problem - if my colleague update jar file - Maven doesn't update it. So I have go to .m2/repository and manually delete it. After this Maven update dependance jar correct.
But may be exists another way to adjust, without each time delete manually?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you should make sure that your colleague's artifact is released with a SNAPSHOT version number as long as it it is not yet stable (see http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-syntax.html#pom-relationships-sect-snapshot-versions). This will cause Maven to check for updates regularily.

To specify how often the check occurs, you can modify the `updatePolicy` of the repository to which your colleague deploys (see http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Repositories). You can set it to `always` to make Maven pull snapshot updates as soon as your colleague deploys them.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add -U to the mvn command to force maven to check the repository for updates (**mvn clean install -U**) but like dosendoc said first make sure you're working off SNAPSHOT versions.